# c++ uniTest Makefile problems

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

I’m working in a software development , in a module that has a directory structure like this :

src:  is the directory where you will be putting the sources you are working on

include:  is the directory where you will be putting the “.h” files

lib :  is where the libraries get installed

bin:   is where the binaries get installed

idl :   is for the Interface Definition language files

object :  is where the dependencies files get installed (when running “ make all ”)

test : is where the test source code has to be put

Now  I'm trying to make Test but I have some problems  with  this makefile

I have a  test/Dummy.cpp file , which is a dummy server that can listen on a specific port and reply a specific requests, there is a utility class VendorServerSocket , which implements the basic communication methods.
But i’m not sure how to implement this class in the makefile (haven't declared),
so when it call the VendorServerScoket show this error.

```
CVRDummy.cpp:39: error: ‘VendorServerSocket’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I have not much experience in software development i'm just learning,i will like to know how can i incorporate this class in my makefile, 
 hope you can help me.

This is the makefile that i’m using:

```
MODULE_NAME = GenericEth



EXECUTABLES_L = Agilent_lanio $(MODULE_NAME)Dummy

$(MODULE_NAME)Dummy_OBJECTS = $(MODULE_NAME)Dummy
$(MODULE_NAME)Dummy_LIBS = $(MODULE_NAME)Eth

Agilent_lanio_OBJECTS = Agilent_lanio
Agilent_lanio_LDFLAGS = -lc

#
# list of all possible C-sources (used to create automatic  dependencies)
# ------------------------------
CSOURCENAMES = \
    $(foreach exe, $(EXECUTABLES) $(EXECUTABLES_L),   $($(exe)_OBJECTS)) \
    $(foreach rtos, $(RTAI_MODULES) , $($(rtos)_OBJECTS)) \
    $(foreach lib, $(LIBRARIES) $(LIBRARIES_L), $($(lib)_OBJECTS))


#>>>>> END OF standard rules

#
# INCLUDE STANDARDS
# -----------------

MAKEDIRTMP := $(shell searchFile include/acsMakefile)
ifneq ($(MAKEDIRTMP),\#error\#)
   MAKEDIR := $(MAKEDIRTMP)/include
   include $(MAKEDIR)/acsMakefile
endif

#
# TARGETS
# -------
all: do_all
    @echo " . . . 'all' done"

clean: clean_all
    $(RM) *~ tatlogs sed.scan tmp .TestList.sed .testSession .purify
    @echo " . . . clean done"

clean_dist: clean clean_dist_all
    @echo " . . . clean_dist done"

man: do_man
    @echo " . . . man page(s) done"

install: install_all
    @echo " . . . installation done"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the header file containing `VendorServerSocket` on top of either `CVRDummy.cpp` or `CVRDummy.hpp`.

Compiler issues different error on `#include "xxx.h"` line, if "xxx.h" is not found during compile time. (assuming `xxx.h` contains the declaration of `VendorServerSocket`.

If you are including the file correctly, then there is a possibility that `VendorServerSocket` is declared in some namespace. You need to access it correctly using scope resolution operator.